# Center website content no matter what the browser size is?

Tags: css

I've just noticed and I should have realized but continuing on, If I zoom in on my website everything is screwed up. I'm not entirely understanding how to get it to center and not move objects around.

Example
Zoomed in
http://gyazo.com/d868f6ebb249c8aa0b4a20e8cba24e86

I'm looking for it to stay centered no matter what you do.

Comment: can you post some css/html?

Comment: where is your html and css source code?

Comment: you should google: "Resposive webdesign" :D I think in this case, this is the best idea :D

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: wrap your whole site in a container `<div>` and give it the id "site-container"

Then add this to your CSS

Fluid width:

```
#site-container
{
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 5%;
}
```

Fixed width:

```
#site-container
{
    width: 900px;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -450px; /* -(width/2) */
}
```

Obviously adjust the sizes as necessary

Comment: Hey GUys, sorry, I had no idea what you would need
here's the following

http://pastebin.com/agtfQXsB

Answer (score 0):

Or with

```
margin: auto;
```

I made you a JSfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/9Mqza/

Comment: Taking a look at it, I think it's my actual elements